# HTTP 500 Internal Server error with PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I am getting Internal Server Error when I use the following code. Do I have to change any configuration? I am using PHP version 5.2.6. I couldn't find any documentation about this issue. Please let me know. Thank you.

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO($db_host1, $db_username, $db_password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
```

Comment: can you share your error log too?

Comment: Have you looked in the webserver (presumably apache) error log for what the error is.  I've never had php cause a 500 error before.

Comment: Where can I find the error log?

Comment: What does your DSN (first param to PDO) look like?

Comment: It's working Now! I have set HTTPD to PHPCGI :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass DSN as first parameter of PDO constructor.

```
try {
    $dsn = "mysql:dbname=testdb;host={$db_host1}";
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $db_username, $db_password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same 500 error after installing php-mysql.

**Solution:**

`Restart the webserver.`

I forgot to restart my webserver, which resolved the problem for me.

***Apache error log said :***

```
> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Undefined class constant
> 'MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND' in /var/www/html/[...].php:8 Stack trace:
> #0 /var/www/html/[...].php(27): myFunction()
> #1 {main}   thrown in /var/www/html/[...].php on line 8, referer: http://localhost/
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31425242)